# PLSQL trigger: override column when row updated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables: 1 with my main data (TABLE: ASSET):

```
ID | DESCR | TYPE1 | COUNTRY
 1 | blabla1 | A1 | AT
 2 | blabla2 | A2 | DE
 3 | blabla3 | A2 | CH
```

and the second table like (TABLE: ASSET_OVERRULE):

```
ID | OVERRULE_COLUMN | OVERRULE_VALUE
 1 | TYPE1           | A2
```

And now I want to have a trigger, which should check the table ASSET_OVERRULE, every time someone update something in the table ASSET. If a entry with the same ID is found, then set the new updated value to the value in the ASSET_OVERRULE.

This is the trigger atm:

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR assets_overrule_cur
  IS
    SELECT *
    FROM asset_overrule
    WHERE id = :NEW.id;
 sTemp VARCHAR2(255):=NULL;
 y NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR assets_overrule 
  IN assets_overrule_cur
  LOOP

    sTemp := ':NEW.' || assets_overrule.OVERRULE_COLUMN || ':=''' ||     assets_overrule.OVERRULE_VALUE|| ''';';

    execute immediate sTemp;     

  END LOOP;
END;
```

But this error appears:

> Knowledge Xpert cannot be found.

I think, I need another solution to solve this problem..

Comment: "Execute immediate" executes SQL, not PL/SQL

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yeah, I already googled that information too, so is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I can't think of an easy method: the attribute-value structure of the override table is not a natural way for a relational database to work, and the tools have to be bent a bit out of shape to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `:new` (or `:old`) pseudorecord in dynamic SQL like that.  You'd need to use static SQL with a separate branch for each column.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_override_val asset_overrule.overrule_value%type;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT overrule_value
      INTO l_override_val
      FROM asset_overrule
     WHERE id = :new.id
       AND override_column = 'TYPE1';
    :new.type1 := l_override_val;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found
    THEN
      NULL;
  END;

  BEGIN
    SELECT overrule_value
      INTO l_override_val
      FROM asset_overrule
     WHERE id = :new.id
       AND override_column = 'COUNTRY';
    :new.country := l_override_val;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found
    THEN
      NULL;
  END;

  <<repeat for each column you want to override>>
END;
```

Taking a step back, the data model appears at the very least to be clunky.  Why have separate rows if you want to override multiple column values rather than letting the definitions of the two tables match?  Do you really need to change the values in a trigger rather than simply doing the overriding in whatever view returns the data so that if you remove the override you go back to whatever the system set the value to?  Wouldn't it make sense for the application that is doing the `UPDATE` to check the override table and either not update those values or alert the user that those values were overridden or something like that?

Comment: OK, good to know (or not^^) that this can't be achieved with a dynamic SQL.. Could you be more specific with 'check the override table and not update those values'?

Comment: @ZerOne - Presumably, you have an application that is generating the DML statement on `asset` (hopefully by calling a procedure).  If that application had logic to query the `asset_override` table then the application could do things like tell the user that a particular column is read-only (since it already has an override) or could avoid updating values that are overridden.  That's generally cleaner than allowing an application to issue an update and surprising the application when you override the values in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it, if I was stuck with this data model:

```
drop table test_asset;

drop table test_asset_overrule;

create table test_asset (id number,
                         descr varchar2(10),
                         type1 varchar2(5),
                         country varchar2(3));

create table test_asset_overrule (id number,
                                  overrule_column varchar2(30),
                                  overrule_value varchar2(10));

insert into test_asset
select 1, 'blabla1', 'A1', 'AT' from dual union all
select 2, 'blabla2', 'A2', 'DE' from dual union all
select 3, 'blabla3', 'A2', 'CH' from dual;

insert into test_asset_overrule
select 1, 'TYPE1', 'A2' from dual;

commit;

create or replace trigger test_asset_trg 
before update on test_asset
for each row
begin
  for rec in (select id,
                     overrule_column,
                     overrule_value
              from   test_asset_overrule
              where  id = :old.id
              and    id = :new.id)
  loop
    if upper(rec.overrule_column) = 'TYPE1' then
      :new.type1 := rec.overrule_value;
    elsif upper(rec.overrule_column) = 'COUNTRY' then
      :new.country := rec.overrule_value;
    end if;
  end loop;
end test_asset_trg;
/

update test_asset
set type1 = 'A3';

commit;

select * from test_asset;

        ID DESCR      TYPE1 COUNTRY
---------- ---------- ----- -------
         1 blabla1    A2    AT     
         2 blabla2    A3    DE     
         3 blabla3    A3    CH
```

Comment: I need to get it dynamic, because there could be also much more columns in different tables..

Comment: no, you don't "need it dynamic". You have a trigger on a table, so you should already know the columns involved in the override for that table. If you're worried about having to write out the code in your trigger for a given table with hundreds of columns, then simply write a sql statement that generates the text for you. eg. `select 'elsif upper(rec.overrule_column) = '''||column_name||''' then||chr(10)||'  :new.'||column_name||' = rec.overrule_value;' from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE_NAME'`. You could then easily edit the results to fit into your trigger code.